# How to have a variable all users can access in PHP?

Tags: php

In my webapp in PHP, I have a button enabling a "critical" situation. What I want is : when a user is clicking on this button, all webbapp users are also in "critical" situation.

I tried to use static, globals, $_SERVER, $GLOBALS, and also with Singleton Pattern for a simple boolean, but nothing is working.

I have a controller with a require_once, a getter and a setter:

```
require_once(ROOT_DIR . 'myapp/src/model/MyClass.php');

$response = MyClass::getInstance();
$allValuesClients["MyVar"] = $response->getVar();


$response = MyClass::getInstance();
$response->setVar($type["MyVar"]);
```

MyClass.php :

```
<?php

class MyClass{
    private static $instance = null;
    private $myvar;

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() {  
        $this->myvar= false;
    }

    public function getVar(){
        return $this->myvar;
    }

    public function setVar($newValue){
        $this->myvar= $newValue;
    }

}


?>
```

Each time I refresh my page, I think that my controller include again the Class file, reseting instance. 
I don't understand how I can do this (with or without controller)

Comment: Set an environment variable or store variables in a database accessible to all.

Comment: What you mean by "user"?

Comment: You need to persist somewhere the fact someone pushed this button (database, env file, session ...)

Comment: In php, variable live until the request completed. For every new request new variable will be created in memory. You need to store this value in db (recommended) or file if you need it in another requests processing.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I thought it was possible to store it with Singleton Class. Thanks for your help